# Unable to launch AVD Emulator in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, android, android-studio

After downloaded and installed Android Studio 3.2, I executed `./studio.sh`. Without doing anything, I test an `hello world` app on Andriod Emulator Nexus 5X API 27 for the first time, however the AVD Emulator does not launch and in Event Log show message as below:

```
10/14/18
12:33 PM    * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

12:33 PM    * daemon started successfully

12:34 PM    Gradle sync started

12:34 PM    Project setup started

12:34 PM    Gradle sync finished in 3 s 396 ms (from cached state)

12:34 PM    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

12:34 PM    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so

12:34 PM    Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing

12:34 PM    Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

12:34 PM    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

12:34 PM    Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

12:34 PM    Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

12:34 PM    Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)

12:34 PM    Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)

12:34 PM    Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0

12:34 PM    Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  56

12:34 PM    Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  57

12:34 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

12:35 PM    Gradle build finished in 47 s 302 ms

12:39 PM    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

12:39 PM    Gradle build finished in 4 s 336 ms

12:39 PM    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so

12:39 PM    Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing

12:39 PM    Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

12:39 PM    Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

12:39 PM    Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

12:39 PM    Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

12:39 PM    Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)

12:39 PM    Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)

12:39 PM    Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0

12:39 PM    Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  56

12:39 PM    Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  57

12:39 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

I did not know what was going wrong with that, the tutorial does not mentioned this kind of error, it just straight forward.

Please kindly help me sort out with this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which was resolved by updating SDK tools which had available updates. You can do this by:

1. **Tools** -> **SDK Manager**
2. Under **SDK Platforms**, select packages that have an update available and select **OK**
3. Under **SDK Tools**, confrim the Android Emulator, Android SDK Platform-Tools and Android SDK Tools are updated to the most current version. If not, select the appropriate developer tools and select **OK** for them to get updated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Kindly consider adding more info onto this answer, like how you actually updated SDK tools. Any commands you run, anything you downloaded, etc. As is, this answer will be flagged as low quality and possibly deleted.

Comment: Thank you @Nick. You deserve a +1